I don't understand this subset of $F^\infty$
From Linear Algebra Done Right, there is a problem that uses a subset of $F^\infty$. The set is
$U$ $=$ {$(x_1, x_2, ... ) \in F^\infty: x_k \neq 0$ for only finitely many k}.
I don't get what this set looks like. Does it mean that an element $u$ $\in U$ is a list with a finite amount of $x$'s that aren't equal to $0$? Does this imply that the additive identity is not in $U$ since it is a list where every $x$ is equal to $0$? I would like an explanation of this set with examples of elements in the set.

If $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=(0,0,0,\ldots)$, then $x_k\ne0$ never occurs. Therefore, the set of those $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_k\ne0$ is the empty set. And $\emptyset$ is a finite set. So, $x\in U$.

As Anne says, the additive identity is in this subset as there are $0$ non-zero entries and $0$ is finite.
A possible reason for this confusion is that in physics, "finite" is sometimes used to mean non-zero.  (I am not saying that it is common or correct, I don't know, but I have heard it.)  However, this is not usual in mathematics, zero is regarded as finite.
You wanted some examples.
The following are in the subset.  In all cases $...$ means that all following entries are $0$.
$$(0, 0, 0, ...)$$ - This is the additive identity.  $0$ non-zero entries.
$$(1, 0, 0, ...)$$ - $1$ non-zero entry.
$$(0, 1, 0, ...)$$
$$(1, 1, 0, ...)$$ - $2$ non-zero entries.
$$(0, 0, 1, ...)$$
You might see that these are similar to counting in binary.
A final included example: the first googolplex entries are $1$ but all following entries are $0$.
The following are not in the subset.  $...$ no longer means all following entries are zero.
$$(1, 1, 1, ...)$$ All following entries are $1$.  If you were doing pointwise multiplcation, this would be the multiplicative identity.
$$(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...)$$ All odd position entries are $1$ and ths others are $0$.
A final comment: the subset is countably infinite but the full set is uncountable.


Does it mean that an element $u\in U$ is a list with a finite amount of $x$'s that aren't equal to $0$?

Yes, this is exactly the definition: $U=\{(x_1, x_2, ... ) \in F^\infty: x_k \neq 0\text{ for only finitely many }k\}$.

Does this imply that the additive identity is not in $U$ since it is a list where every $x$ is equal to $0$?

No, in the case $u=$ the additive identity, the "amount of $x$'s that aren't equal to $0$" is just zero, which is finite. So, $u\in U$.
